# BIRT Report not connected with sql server jdbc 4.0

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2012, birt

When I deployed sample test report in apache tomcat 7.0.67, it was running correctly and another report connected with SQL server 2012. Report design preview is also working. BIRT report design manage driver, jdbc driver have been added and test connection found ok.

sqljdbc4.0.jar has been added to the  `Apache tomact BIRT\WEBINF\lib`

but local host showing following error:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details: 
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc. Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. 
Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
```

Comment: Have you **removed** sqljdbc.jar?

Comment: You must remove it, you have to have only one of them on the classpath. So, remove `sqljdbc.jar`, and only leave `sqljdbc4.jar`.

Comment: in CLASS_PATH I have configured only one jdbc4.jar C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0.1301.101_enu\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: BIRT design I have create design report connected with SQL server database com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver ( v3.0) In manage driver sqljdbc4.jar Preview data shown and same rpt design file i have copy and paste it to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\birt

Comment: JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin